# Как передать значение переменной функции из одного класса в другой класс

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Дана переменная `data`, которая находится в классе `Demo`, в функции `on_click` При нажатии на нее, открывается файл. Так же есть класс `OCR` с функцией `recognise_file`. Необходимо в функции `recognise_file` использовать значение переменной `data` из класса `Demo`.

Пример кода:

```py
class Demo(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Demo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

    def on_click(self):
        self.data = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Открытие файла', './', "Изображения (*.png *.jpg *jpeg)")
        self.lineEdit.setText(self.data[0])

        

class OCR(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(OCR, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.recognise_file)
        
    def recognise_file(self):
        if isinstance(self.data, tuple):
            self.data = self.data[0]  # Qt4/5 API difference
        if self.data == '':
          return
        data_r = {'file': open(self.data, 'rb')}
        url = 'https:test.api'
        response = requests.post(url, auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('43543gfdfgdfgtdgf', ''), files=data_r)
        data_file = response.json()
        if data_file['message']=='Success':
            print("Изображение успешно распознано")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = Demo()

    Form.show()  # Показать основную форму

    sys.exit(app.exec_())  # Ожидание выхода из программы в цикле
```

Но если внизу

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = Demo()

    Form.show()  # Показать основную форму

    sys.exit(app.exec_())  # Ожидание выхода из программы в цикле
```

В строке `Form = Demo()`  указать название класса `OCR` выполнятся будет код уже из класса `OCR` , как сделать выполнение из нескольких классов?

Comment: Сделать еще один экземпляр класса, только класса OCR? А потом из него достать переменную?

Answer (score 0):

```
def recognise_file(self):
    demo = Demo() # создаешь экземпляр класса Demo
                  # и используешь demo.data
    if isinstance(demo.data, tuple):
        demo.data = self.data[0]  # Qt4/5 API difference
    if demo.data == '':
        return
    data_r = {'file': open(demo.data, 'rb')}
    url = 'https:test.api'
    response = requests.post(url, auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('43543gfdfgdfgtdgf', ''), files=data_r)
    data_file = response.json()
    if data_file['message'] == 'Success':
        print("Изображение успешно распознано")
```

Добавил комментарии в твой код, ты это имел введу

```
demo = Demo() # создаешь экземпляр класса Demo
              # и используешь demo.data
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую.